# Помощь с кодом программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код для нахождения сторон прямоугольника.

```
class R():

    def __init__( self, bottomLeft, topRight ):
        self.x0 = bottomLeft[0]
        self.y0 = bottomLeft[1]
        self.x1 = topRight[0]
        self.y1 = topRight[1]

    def S( self ):
        return (self.x1 - self.x0) * (self.y1 - self.y0)

    def crossX( self ):
        return self.x0 < 0 < self.x1

    def crossY( self ):
        return self.y0 < 0 < self.y1

s = R ([-2,-1],[2,2])
print(s.S())
```

и код для генерирования рандомных точек

```
class Point:

    def rn( self ):
        r = range( 100 )
        x, y = random.choices( r, k=2 )
        print( x, y )
```

как генерацию рандомных точек подставить в `s = R ([-2,-1],[2,2])` что б не вписывать другие каждый раз ну или ввод с клавы правильный оформить

Comment: Я так понимаю вы хотите чтоб каждый раз когда вы вызвали класс R вместо пользовательских  аргументов были рандомные значения?Можете подробней рассказать о вашей задаче.

Comment: @Gleb Задача о нахождении 2х прямоугольников и узнать пересекаются ли они, прямоугольники могут быть разные, на то и рандомные точки

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал избавиться от избыточного класса и написать функцию, которая просто возвращает координаты:

```
import random

def random_rect():
    max = 100
    x, y = random.randint(0, max), random.randint(0, max)
    width, height = random.randint(1, max), random.randint(1, max)
    x1, y1 = x + width, y + height
    return ([x, y], [x1, y1])

s = R (*random_rect())
```